# Change year/quarter date format to previous period in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataset containing monthly observations of a time-series. 
What I want to do is transform the datetime to year/quarter format and then extract the first value `DATE[0]` as the previous quarter. For example 2006-10-31 belongs to 4Q of 2006. But I want to change it to 2006Q3. 
For the extraction of the subsequent values I will just use the last value from each quarter. 
So, for 2006Q4 I will keep BBGN, SSD, and QQ4567 values only from `DATE[2]`. Similarly, for 2007Q1 I will keep only `DATE[5]` values, and so forth.

Original dataset:

```
               DATE                BBGN    SSD             QQ4567  
    0  2006-10-31 00:00:00        1.210  22.022          9726.550   
    1  2006-11-30 00:00:00        1.270  22.060          9891.008   
    2  2006-12-31 00:00:00        1.300  22.080         10055.466   
    3  2007-01-31 00:00:00        1.330  22.099         10219.924   
    4  2007-02-28 00:00:00        1.393  22.110         10350.406
    5  2007-03-31 00:00:00        1.440  22.125         10480.888
```

After processing the DATE

```
       DATE          BBGN    SSD             QQ4567  
    0  2006Q3        1.210  22.022          9726.550   
    2  2006Q4        1.300  22.080         10055.466   
    5  2007Q1        1.440  22.125         10480.888
```

The steps I have taken so far are:

Turn the values from the yyyy-mm-dd hh format to yyyyQQ format

```
DF['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['DATE']).dt.to_period('Q')
```

and I get this

```
    DATE          BBGN    SSD             QQ4567  
0  2006Q4        1.210  22.022          9726.550   
1  2006Q4        1.270  22.060          9891.008   
2  2006Q4        1.300  22.080         10055.466   
3  2007Q1        1.330  22.099         10219.924   
4  2007Q1        1.393  22.110         10350.406
5  2007Q1        1.440  22.125         10480.888
```

The next step is to extract the last values from each quarter. But because I always want to keep the first row I will exclude `DATE[0]` from the function.

```
quarterDF = DF.iloc[1:,].drop_duplicates(subset='DATE', keep='last')
```

Now, my question is how can I change the value in `DATE[0]` to always be the previous quarter. So, from 2006Q4 to be 2006Q3. Also, how this will work if `DATE[0]` is 2007Q1, can I change it to 2006Q4?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you want to report quarterly, but show every quarter as the quarter before, am I right? 

I feel like (and I could be wrong) that this will be difficult, because you're kind of going against what Pandas understands as quarters.

Comment: Hi Graig, actually I need to do that only for the first row. So, if the first row belongs to 2017Q1 I would like to change it to 2016Q4. But only for the first row. I have created a table as an output to visualise what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a new `DATE` column with a day 3 months in the past. Like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(['2006-10-31', '2007-01-31'])
one_quarter = pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
df['Last_quarter'] = df.Date - one_quarter
```

This will give you

```
    Date    Last_quarter
0   2006-10-31  2006-07-31
1   2007-01-31  2006-10-31
```

Then you can do the same process as you described above on `Last_quarter`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `pivot_table` approach

```
# Subtract the quarter from date save it in a column 
df['Q'] = df['DATE'] - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()

#0   2006-09-30
#1   2006-09-30
#2   2006-09-30
#3   2006-12-31
#4   2006-12-31
#5   2006-12-31
#Name: Q, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# Drop and pivot for not including the columns 
ndf = df.drop(['DATE','Q'],1).pivot_table(index=pd.to_datetime(df['Q']).dt.to_period('Q'),aggfunc='last')

      BBGN     QQ4567     SSD
Qdate                          
2006Q3  1.30  10055.466  22.080
2006Q4  1.44  10480.888  22.125
```